# Cometd Seti getUserIds() and getPresenceCount(userId) returns empty list alternatively

Tags: spring, cometd

seti.getUserIds()) returns empty list on **publishMessage** method alternatively. The client is not disconnected and seti presenceRemoved is not fired. However, seti.getUserIds()) returns the userId list with correct values in **listenMetaChannel**. Seti is not Null in publishMessage  method. Seti is properly injected in this class.

```
@Singleton
    @Named 
    @Service("notificationService")
    public class NotificationService {

        @Session
        private ServerSession serverSession;
        private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

        @Autowired
        private BayeuxServer bayeuxServer;

        @Autowired
        private Seti seti;

        @Configure("/notification")
                public void configureChannel(ConfigurableServerChannel channel)
                {
                    channel.setPersistent(true);// channel persistent
                    channel.addAuthorizer(GrantAuthorizer.GRANT_ALL);   
                    //channel.setLazy(true);

                }


        public void publishMessage( String messageId ,String userId)
        {
            logger.debug("Seti Session USERS::"+seti.getUserIds()); 

            String  userId="568";
            boolean userPresent=seti.isPresent(userId);
                if(userPresent){
                     Map<String, Object> push_data= new HashMap<String, Object>();
                     push_data.put("messageId", messageId);
                    seti.sendMessage(userId, "/channel", push_data);
                }else
                {
                    logger.debug("User ::"+userId+" Session Absent !! ");
                }


     } 

            @Listener(Channel.META_CONNECT)  
            public void listenMetaChannel(ServerSession remote, ServerMessage message)
            {   

                logger.debug("Seti Session USERS::"+seti.getUserIds());

            }

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "returns empty list alternatively" ? The code above does not compile (variable `crewId` is not defined), so it is difficult to say something. If you have a reproducible test case, please submit it to http://bugs.cometd.org, but I strongly suggest that you review your code, as it is unlikely that it's a CometD issue.

Comment: crewId is replaced with userId, when an external spring bean method calls the publishMessage for the first time the users connected to the oort cloud are printed. For the second method call, the seti.getUserIds() returns 0 users. However, seti.getUserIds() in  listenMetaChannel returns all connected users in the cloud properly  all the time.

Comment: I have doubts that the same call returns different results depending on what method is being called.
As said, if you have double checked your code, and you have a reproducible test case, please submit it at http://bugs.cometd.org.
Oort questions tend to be complicated to explain and resolve due to the nature of the many parts involved, so you are welcome to join the CometD mailing lists to explain your case in greater details. What provided here is not enough, and you have still not explained what you meant by "returns empty list alternatively", nor when these methods are called, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I will provide a complete scenario in cometd users group with code.

Comment: The details can be found in the link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25899082/cometd-oort-seti-seti-getuserids-returns-incorrect-users-in-the-oort-cloud-or